# Passing special characters via HTTP Post

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I am trying to pass special characters but it is not working.I already specified UTF8String string.I am trying to pass "å ø æ"  it prints like "$@\U20ac\U00a3\U00a5".

```
     NSMutableDictionary* reqDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [reqDict setObject:Userid forKey:@"user_id"];
    [reqDict setObject:Comm_id forKey:@"comm_id"];
    [reqDict setObject:Post_id forKey:@"post_id"];
    [reqDict setObject:Comment_type forKey:@"comment_type"];
    [reqDict setObject:Comment forKey:@"comment"];
    //[reqDict setObject:@"å ø æ" forKey:@"comment"];

    NSLog(@"Comment:%@",reqDict);
    NSString* reqString = [NSString stringWithString:[reqDict JSONRepresentation]];

    //Request
    NSData* requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[reqString UTF8String] length:[reqString length]];
   // NSLog(@"requestData:%@",requestData);
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tiComment_url]];

    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"ASIHTTPRequest"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]]];

    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
    request.defaultResponseEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
    [request appendPostData:requestData];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:60];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startSynchronous];
```

Comment: How are you creating "$@\U20ac\U00a3\U00a5"? \U20ac\U00a3\U00a5 produces: €£¥.

Comment: may i need to change reqString to NSUTF8StringEncoding instead of UTF8String

Comment: I'm guessing that your "Comment" value was wrong to begin with.  You created it without using a UTF character set.

Answer (score 0):

NSLog will print extended characters in escaped form. The characters are still (presumably) correct in the string. (Remember, NSLog is not intended for "production", only debug, and many debugging environmments would have trouble displaying the extended characters.)

Comment: Some what true but not in the case. @"\u20ac\u00a3\u00a5" NSLogs as €£¥.  @"å ø æ" NSLogs as  å ø æ.

Comment: @Zaph - Yeah, apparently the OP also has a charset problem.